# Postgres partition by week

Tags: sql, postgresql, partitioning, week-number

I can imagine table partition by a date (in particular for logs) is something widely used, but I am not able to find a good answer to my problem.

I want to create a table partition by week (the number of records is to big to make it monthly). The reason for it to be weekly is that I need the data for an algorithm that will be looking for dates as part of the process.

My problem is I want it to create the partitions considering the week and using the "typical" approach I would have to be creating it manually. Something like this.

```
    CREATE TABLE measurement_y2013w01 (
CHECK ( logdate >= DATE '2013-01-07' AND logdate < DATE '2013-01-14' ) 
    ) INHERITS (measurement);

    CREATE TABLE measurement_y2006w02 (
CHECK ( logdate >= DATE '2013-01-14' AND logdate < DATE '2013-01-21' ) 
    ) INHERITS (measurement);

...
```

But I want it to be made automatically. I don't want to be creating a partition for every week one by one.

My rule for name giving would be yYYYYwWW for the naming of the partition or start datadYYYYMMDD.

I thought in checking for partitions when inserting using something like this:

```
 SELECT
    nmsp_parent.nspname AS parent_schema,
    parent.relname      AS parent,
    nmsp_child.nspname  AS child,
    child.relname       AS child_schema
FROM pg_inherits
    JOIN pg_class parent        ON pg_inherits.inhparent = parent.oid
    JOIN pg_class child         ON pg_inherits.inhrelid   = child.oid
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_parent   ON nmsp_parent.oid  = parent.relnamespace
    JOIN pg_namespace nmsp_child    ON nmsp_child.oid   = child.relnamespace
```

and if the partition is not there create it before the insert, but this seams a lot inefficient, considering the number of records inserted.

My other alternative is to have an external process running weekly creating this partition, but I was trying to avoid this.

Is there a more efficient solution for this that I am missing, that is used, for example, for monthly checks?

Comment: You will have an external process deleting or moving old partitions won't you? If so what is the problem with it creating partitions?

Comment: You might want to have a look at pg_partman, which can automate many things regarding partitioning for you: https://github.com/keithf4/pg_partman/blob/master/doc/pg_partman.md

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so let's create ourselves a function to handle that!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_partition_measurement( DATE, DATE )
returns void AS $$
DECLARE
create_query text;
BEGIN
    FOR create_query IN SELECT

        'CREATE TABLE measurement_' || TO_CHAR( d, 'YYYY_WW' ) || ' (
        CHECK ( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM logdate) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP ''' || d || ''') AND EXTRACT(WEEK FROM logdate) = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP ''' || d || ''') )
        ) INHERITS (measurement);'

        FROM generate_series( $1, $2, '1 week' ) AS d LOOP

        EXECUTE create_query;

    END LOOP;
END;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

With this you can now call something like

```
SELECT create_partition_measurement ('2015/02/08','2015/03/01');
```

and have your partitions created. First step to automation, done.

I tested all this in my own database using the following test table:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, id_user INT NOT NULL, logdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL);
```

After creating the partitions using the function above, I was able to:

- Insert data into the correct partition;
- Get an error when trying to insert data from one week into another week's partition;
- Automatically create partition for several weeks, and;
- Get an error should I try to create a partition for a week where one already exists.

This should be enough =)

Now, about automating the creation process. I use a simple cron script to call this function for me every month and a couple of monitoring scripts to make sure everything is working as it should.
The cron looks like this:

```
0 0 1 * * /var/lib/postgresql/create_partitions.sh
```

And the script will run the command using the current date and the current date + 1 month. It looks something like this:

```
startDate=`date "+%Y/%m/%d"`
endDate=`date -u -d "+1 month -$(date +%d) days" "+%Y/%m/%d"
psql -U "$dbUser" -w -c "SELECT create_partition_measurement('$startDate','$endDate');"
```

If you need to include indexes, PKs, FKs in the table, or help with the triggers to make all this work, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **date_trunc** function to round data value to the first day of the week. For partition naming you could use year and week number in the year **YYWW**:

```
CREATE TABLE measurement_1301 (
    CHECK ( date_trunc( 'week', logdate )::date = DATE '2013-01-07') )
    INHERITS (measurement);

CREATE TABLE measurement_1302 (
    CHECK ( date_trunc( 'week', logdate )::date = DATE '2013-01-14') )
    INHERITS (measurement);

CREATE TABLE measurement_1303 (
    CHECK ( date_trunc( 'week', logdate )::date = DATE '2013-01-21') )
    INHERITS (measurement);

-- Default partition:
CREATE TABLE measurement_default () INHERITS (measurement);
```

For partition name generation use `to_char( logdate::date, 'YYWW')` and if you if you prefer **yYYYYwWW**: `to_char( logdate::date, '"y"YYYY"w"WW')`

And to check the existing partitions you could use very simple query:

```
SELECT relname FROM pg_class
WHERE relname ~ '^measurement_[0-9]{4}$'
ORDER BY RIGHT(relname,4) DESC
```

Data routing trigger inserts into appropriate partition and fall back to the default, if there is no partition for the given week.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION measurement_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN

    IF to_char( NEW.logdate::date, 'YYWW') = '1301' THEN
        INSERT INTO measurement_1301 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF to_char( NEW.logdate::date, 'YYWW') = '1302' THEN
        INSERT INTO measurement_1302 VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF to_char( NEW.logdate::date, 'YYWW') = '1303' THEN
        INSERT INTO measurement_1303 VALUES (NEW.*);
    -- ...
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO measurement_default VALUES (NEW.*);
    END IF;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER measurement_insert_tr BEFORE INSERT ON measurement
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE measurement_insert_trigger()
```

You will have create in advance all partitions. Or you can use the default partition and time to time re-partition the data stored there, creating new partitions and adjusting the insert trigger.

PS you can find scripts for partitioning solution based on triggers here http://hg.nowitworks.eu/postgresql-triggers-and-partitions

Comment: +1 because it was useful for most of the steps. Still doesn't answer completely the main part of creating partition if they don't exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one insertion trigger that creates the partition if it doesn't exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_measurement_partition()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
    _tbl text := to_char(NEW.logdate, '"measurement_y"IYYY_"w"IW');
    _rec_date date := NEW.logdate::date;
    _min_date date := date_trunc('week', NEW.logdate)::date;
    _max_date date := date_trunc('week', NEW.logdate)::date + 7;
    _min_live date := date_trunc('week', NEW.logdate)::date - 1;
BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'
    AND    c.relname = _tbl
    AND    c.relkind = 'r') THEN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %I
                    (CHECK (logdate::date >= to_date(%L, ''yyyy-mm-dd'') AND
                            logdate::date <  to_date(%L, ''yyyy-mm-dd'')),
                        LIKE measurement INCLUDING INDEXES )
                        INHERITS (measurement)'
            , _tbl
            , to_char(_min_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            , to_char(_max_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            );
    IF (_rec_date >= _min_date) and (_rec_date < _max_date) THEN
        EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_measurement AS (
                            SELECT * FROM measurement
                            WHERE (logdate::date >= to_date(%L, ''yyyy-mm-dd'') AND
                                logdate::date <  to_date(%L, ''yyyy-mm-dd''))
                        )'
                , to_char(_min_live, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                , to_char(_max_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                );
    END IF;
END IF;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || quote_ident(_tbl) || ' VALUES ($1.*)'
USING NEW;
RETURN NULL;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SET search_path = public;


DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS ins_measurement on measurement;
CREATE TRIGGER ins_measurement
BEFORE INSERT ON measurement
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_measurement_partition();
```

The trigger performs the following tasks:

1. Check if the table exists (querying `pg_catalog` is very fast).
2. Calculate the name of the corresponding table for the records `logdate`
3. In case the partition table with that name doesn't exist, create a new one for the corresponding week (`CREATE TABLE ... LIKE measurement INCLUDING INDEXES INHERITS (measurement)`)
4. Create or update a view called `v_measurement` for the data of the last week.

The answer assumes that an empty `measurement` table exists as template and that the `logdate` field is `timestamp`. In that table, it is better to create one index for the `logdate` field typecasted to date:

```
drop index if exists measurement_logdate_part_idx;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX measurement_logdate_part_idx
ON measurement((logdate::date) DESC NULLS LAST, id);
```

The code was adapted from another similar stackoverflow response.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps, I wrote a postgres trigger to create a table that is automatically partitioned by day.  Creating inherited tables happens automatically.  To partition by week you would have to change the day->string mapping and that's it.

https://github.com/bitdivine/pg_day_partitions